# Multiprocessing Executing python script command with looping arguments

Tags: python, list, arguments, command-line-arguments

I have python script called `generate_the_result.py`. The results can be produced by executing that script with one argument. For example `generate_the_result.py my_arg_01`

I have a file which the content is the list of arguments of the script.

```
## my list of arguments
my_arg_01
my_arg_02
my_arg_03
my_arg_04
my_arg_05
.
.
.
```

I want to execute each argument inside my file above on the `generate_the_result.py`script one by one by looping. How is the best way to do that in python?

there are a lot of arguments inside the file,

a possible solution is read the file, do loop, inside the loop execute `subprocess.call("generate_the_result.py [i]")` but is this the best way?

Comment: You can start by reading the arguments from the file... and then starting the other script with those arguments... and then you're done. Really, what's the problem? Reading text from files and starting processes are two easy (and easily googleable) tasks.

Comment: are you on Linux?

Comment: I'm closing this with a relevant dup. Just read in your arguments and run your function with each, in a loop, in the script.

Comment: I was going to propose a multiprocessing solution using shell as an alternative to feed in arguments

Comment: @eagle, I am not sure the question is about multiprocessing. If user updates the question, then by all means this can be reopened if not a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, could you pls give me hint to do that @eagle ?

Comment: you have to edit the question if that's what you want otherwise its a dupe

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the best way is to give that file path which contains args and write the results into another output file. If file in csv format you can easily iterate aruments.

`generate_the_result.py file_name.csv`